# Set view finder in nvd3 line chart to specific time on x scale

Tags: javascript, time, focus, nvd3.js

I can't figure out how to initialize view finder in nvd3 lineWithFocusChart for exmaple for last 3 days. I have timestamp stored in 'Data'. Chart looks fine, but I don't know how to set it to focus on specific time (example. I have data from 1 year period and I would like to look at last month at page load). I was trying add brushExtent without any results.

```
function drawLineChart(id, Data, width, height){
    var ch = nv.addGraph(function() {

    var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart()
    .width(width)
    .height(height)
    .x(function(d){return d.x})
    .y(function(d){return d.y});

data = [
    {
        key: "Waga",
        values: []
    }
];
for(var i=0; i<Data.data.trackers[0].measurements.length; i++){ // parse data to fit line chart structure
    data[0].values.push({x: Data.data.trackers[0].measurements[i].date, y: parseFloat(Data.data.trackers[0].measurements[i].value)});
}

chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d * 1000))
  });

chart.x2Axis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d * 1000));
  });


chart.yAxis
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

chart.y2Axis
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));




d3.select("#"+id+" svg")
  .datum(data)
  .call(chart); 

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
}
```

Comment: So dump... I should just add chart.brushExtent([min,max]) but I was thinking I should set min/max as Date objects because it was formated to date. Nope. It's neccessery to set min/max values as it is in data we send to chart. SOLVED

Comment: You can post it as an answer. It will be helpful to others. If you aren't active on StackOverflow, I can post it as an answer on your behalf.

Comment: I found here an example that deals with dates. http://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/dd86d40174de7d594f71